# How Do I Access an Object Property By Index Using Spacebars in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Anyone know how to access a numeric property with Meteor spacebars?

Answer (score 3):

After some guess work I sussed it out as I was writing the question! Let's say you have a 'size' object like so, and you want to access 70.

```
size: {
 70: 10,
 10: 80,
 20: 10
}
```

Use the following in your template file:

```
{{size.[70]}} // Will return 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Glad to hear that you figured it out on your own. Not sure if you happened to see it, but the documentation for Spacebars can be found [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md). The section that covers the issue you have identified in your original question is called Identifiers and Paths near the top of the page.

Per the documentation, in order to access a specific index in a data context object, the numeric index must be enclosed in brackets like so:

```
foo.[0]
```

Comment: I didn't see this but I have now added this to my bookmarks. Thanks very much for pointing this out!